# Adjust the shape of figures with/without colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code to plot a figure.
When I run this code without adding plt.colorbar(), I can get a figure which looks more like a rectangle. However, if I add colorbar, the shape change to look like a square.

How can I add colorbar and maintain the original shape of the figure? Thanks!!!

```
#%%
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()

x = np.random.rand(10000)
y = np.random.rand(10000)
plt.scatter(x,y,c=y)
#plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The colorbar steals space from the axes.  If you want the axes to be wider, it’s easy to just make the figure wider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html), you need to add some settings to axes. Your script works for me in a right ways if I insert these rows after creation of `fig`:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
```